# Linux C/C++ or bash script: Determining a drive/device type

Tags: linux, drive

I would like to be able to determine the type of a drive/device (CDROM, Floppy, Fixed Hard drive, Removable drive, etc.) in Linux either using C/C++ or bash script.

I will be given a mount point path, and I will need to display the source drive type of that mount point.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the device node itself you can look under `/sys/block` or `/sys/dev/block` for its various characteristics.

Comment: You can find the block devices for your mounts in /proc/mounts.

Comment: I am not sure if I follow on what I should be looking for in those directories. Note that I will be getting the mount points and can execute stat on them, which will give me the stat.st_dev value. I am still having trouble joining that with the above posted tip to determine if the path is on a floppy, HDD, CDROM, etc.

Comment: If you have the device number then you probably won't need anything else; the major numbers for floppy and optical are well-defined.

Comment: Thanks. I found this document: http://www.linux-tutorial.info/modules.php?name=MContent&pageid=94. I there anything a little more straight forward?

Comment: As the bottom of that article says, check `devices.txt` for the various values.

Comment: Thanks again. I am still looking for something a little simpler.